# How can I prevent the Package Manager Console from hanging when cmdlet prompts for info?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I've been using NuGet's Package Manager Console for any command line activities I need to perform while working in Visual Studio.  It works great since I don't need to leave VS, but when cmdlets prompt for more information (user id, password, confirmation, etc ...) it just hangs and I have to restart VS.

Is there anyway to tweak Package Manager Console to behave like a standard Power Shell console for user prompts?

Comment: It behaves normally for me, prompts and all. Do you load any other modules? What version powershell? Do you have anything in the file referenced by `$Profile`?

Comment: Thanks @Eris, get-module returns: NuGet & profile, and profile has no ExportedCommands. The file $Profile points to does not exist. When you say you don't have this problem, does git or hg prompt you for server credentials when you push?  That's when it usually hangs for me, but even when git difftool prompts for a confirmation [Y/n], it hangs.  I haven't seen anything which has a command line prompt which doesn't hang.

Comment: Git does not, since I use git-credential-winstore (http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) for command line, and have the git SCM plugin (from the add-ons manager). For difftool, I use "git difftool -g -d <commit/branch ids>" which never prompts, and opens in KDiff3 the entire diff, not one file at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Eris, I realize I may be able to configure git & hg to not prompt me, and I've done that in the past, but every once in a while I run into something new where it does prompt me, and the console does hang, so I thought perhaps I should see if I can configure that instead.  KWIM?

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre, did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: @andrecarlucci No, the only solution I was able to figure out was to either a) prevent the prompt (like using SSH keys for github & bitbucket) or b) use powershell outside VS (this is what I usually do).  Mind you, I haven't tried to figure it out yet in VS2013.

Answer (score 2):

Like PowerShell ISE, the NuGet package manager console is implemented in WPF. It's not a real console window. It works perfectly well for promoting with native Cmdlets, but it doesn't handle native commands (com/exe) stdin redirection. The ISE suffers from the same failing. I did think about implementing it but the work required was disproportionately large for the perceived benefit. You can use response files or pipe responses to the native command a lot of a time, so there are workarounds. Try running an interactive command like netsh in ISE to see what happens.